# Data type mismatch when reading an Excel column

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to read an Excel file where all column of excel has General format. I get the error about data type mismatch. How should I rewrite the sql criteria or which data type is suitable for working with SQL queries?

```
SELECT [duration] FROM [result$] where 
(
[destination]='" & x &"' or 
([destination]='802' and [Dst# Channel] like '%Local/"& x &"%')
)  
and [source]<'100' and [source]>'200'
```

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

I have to say that I set IMEX=1in connection String;

```
ExcelConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & 
ExcelFile & "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
```

Comment: Have you looked for worksheet error codes in the column? (F5, Special, Formulas, Errors)

Comment: There is no error but I guess that the error comes from NULL values. @Jeeped